# Balena Etcher flashes USB-stick into wierd format?

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, usb-drive, iso

I used Etcher to flash Pop!_OS 19.10 to my USB-stick in Windows.

After the process was done, Windows did not recognize the USB anymore.

When I plugged it into my Linux Mint laptop, it showed up as 2 devices, the 1st one was named after the distro iso "Pop!_OS 19.10" which contained the install media related files and second device was "casper" which contained crashes and logs.

The "Pop!_OS" device showed as "isofs" format and "casper" as "ext3/ext4".

I already had used the stick to install Pop!_OS to another machine so I re-formatted the stick back to FAT32 with the built-in formatting tool in Linux Mint.

Is this normal for Etcher? That the USB is no longer recognized in Windows after the flashing?

I did not find any settings that would allow to set the format for flashing.

I've been using Rufus for a while, but had to use Etcher since Pop!_OS install failed when using Rufus for flashing the install-media.

Comment: what failure are you experiencing? ... why do you believe that windows should be able to access the flash drive?

Comment: I just feel that it is inconvenient that you have to reformat the drive on a Linux machine if you want to re-use it in Windows again. That's why I preferred Rufus since it formatted the stick in FAT32 when flashing Linux install media. Even after the flashing I could still access the stick if I wanted to reformat it for other use.

Comment: yeah, i know what you mean ... microsoft should get their heads out of the sand and configure windows to read more than just a couple of disk firmats

Comment: you are misunderstanding the fact that it is the image file that determines if the resulting drive will be readable by windows, not the software that "burns" the image file into the usb druve