# Why is my live USB still MBR after flashing POP_OS! with Etcher?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

Similar to the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559550/balena-etcher-flashes-usb-stick-into-wierd-format), I have questions about burning POP_OS! with Etcher.

After burning the image to a USB stick, I still see it as "MBR" when I view its properties in Disk Manager. The main SSD, however, is GPT. Another guide on SE suggests having the USB partitioning scheme set to match that of the main SSD / HDD (GPT -> GPT, MBR -> MBR).

Does this mismatch I have cause issues when dual-booting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Debian installed at MBR, Gentoo at GTP and Windows 10 as MBR. There are no issues with multi-boot if you don't use UEFI bios. UEFI requires GPT for all drives to make them bootable. GPT and MBR are two different ways of storing information about partitions on the disk.

> After burning the image to a USB stick, I still see it as "MBR"

There is nothing wrong with this. When you extract a Linux .iso image to the USB stick, it extracts partitioning as well and makes this drive bootable. When you boot it and start the installation, this process will create a new partition table on your desired disk and usually let you choose between GPT or MBR.

Comment: I have a single SSD which I shrunk to make space for Linux. I am hoping that the new partition which will have Linux being MBR won't be an issue?

Comment: @LittleChild Partition table (GPT or MBR) is related to a single disk. If your SDD has GPT as you say, it will stay GPT.

Comment: What I meant to ask is that if I try to install an MBR POP_OS! from USB on a GPT partition of a GPT SSD, am I going to run into trouble?

Comment: Partitioning of installer will not necessarily be partitioning of your install. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. And with Ubuntu you can install UEFI to MBR, if install drive is already MBR, but really should not, so just make sure to use gpt on the drive you are installing into. Some tools that create installer only create BIOS/MBR or UEFI/gpt configurations on install media.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, Etcher created BIOS/MBR on the USB. The SSD has GPT/UEFI. So like you said, I'm installing into a GPT media.